# JavaScript-Getting Clicked Item To Text Box On Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox, mousedown

I have an asp.net web page. I want to get clicked li's id into TextBox.

**If i use code like this**==

```
$('ul li').mousedown(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'));});
```

This code give me id which I want.

**But If I use code like this to test textbox content**==

```
document.getElementById("TextBox").value=$('ul li').mousedown(function(){ { return $(this).attr('id')});

alert( document.getElementById("TextBox").value );
```

This code give me an alert like **[object Object]**.

All asp code is that

```
<table id="table-1">
 <% int i =0;
 Response.Write("<tr>");
 system.data.dataset ds= getUl();
 foreach(system.data.DataRow k in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 { if(i%3 == 0) { Response.Write("</tr><tr>"); }
   Response.Write("<td onmouseup='toTextBox()'>");
   Response.Write("<ul class='sortable-list' id="+k[0].ToString()+">");

   system.Data.Dataset dsc= getLi(Convert.ToInt32(k["ID"].ToString()));

foreach(system.data.DataRow k in dsc.Tables[0].Rows)
{  


 Response.Write(" <li class='item' id="+s[0].ToString()+"></li>");


  }
Response.Write("</ul>");
Response.Write("</tr>");
%>
</table>

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

There can be errors. I wrote it not copy-paste because codes are on a computer without internet.

How can I get clicked li's content to textbox correctly?

Thanks For Your Helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
$('ul li').mousedown(function() {
    $("#txtBoxId").val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Result is [object Object] again.

Comment: provide your html please

Comment: <ul class='sortable-list' id="+k[0].ToString()+">  <li class='item' id="+s[0].ToString()+"></li>  <ul> ----- <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> /// These is part of code. I hope you can help

Comment: Ids are coming from mssql.

Comment: i can help more quickly if you provide Rendered HTML for this aspx markup

Comment: I added it to my answer.

Comment: i told you to provide html which renders in browser for the code which you have written in aspx

Comment: use this line instead of your Response.Write("<li class='item' id='"+s[0].ToString()+"'></li>");

Comment: unfortunately same result again... Did not change anything

Comment: Is there anyway of posting clicked li on asp's c# code without ajax?

Comment: @serdanarik - why are You not posting the generated html ?

Comment: I need only content of clicked li. For example Update(contentLi1). Because of this I m trying to send with textBox

Comment: use $(this).html() instead of $(this).attr('id')

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul.sortable-list').on('mousedown', 'li', function(event){
   $('#<%=TextBox.ClientID %>').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Remove extra '{' from your mousedown function. Don't mix javascript and jquery.

**Update:**

```
<table id="table-1">
 <% int i = 0;
 Response.Write("<tr>");
 System.ata.dataset ds= getUl();
 foreach(system.data.DataRow k in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
 { 
  if(i%3 == 0) 
   { 
    Response.Write("</tr><tr>"); 
   }
   Response.Write("<td onmouseup='toTextBox()'>");
   Response.Write("<ul class='sortable-list' id='"+k[0].ToString()+"'>");
   system.Data.Dataset dsc= getLi(Convert.ToInt32(k["ID"].ToString()));
   foreach(system.data.DataRow k in dsc.Tables[0].Rows)
   {  
    Response.Write("<li class='item' id='"+s[0].ToString()+"'></li>");
   }
   Response.Write("</ul>");
   Response.Write("</tr>");
   i++;
   %>
 }
</table>
```

Comment: I took same result. And Sorry I m new :)

Comment: @serdanarik, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: I tried this too, but still same result. I do not know where the problem is?